# How to install catdoc on Mac (without using macports)

Tags: macos, makefile, gnu-make

## background

I really would like to search for a term in a directory full of Word docs. So I stumbled across this [lovely solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14537727/766570). However this solution requires that catdoc is installed on mac.

## what I have tried

now homebrew obviously doens't have catdoc:

```
$ brew install catdoc
Updating Homebrew...
Error: No available formula with the name "catdoc"
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

macports does, but I use homebrew and It's not a [good idea](https://superuser.com/a/181345/234141) to have both on my machine.

So I did what any self respecting semi-programmer would do: try to install it from [source](https://github.com/petewarden/catdoc):

```
$ ./configure
```

see [outpout](https://gist.github.com/abbood/fee1b36266d567b0872cef9681448213)

```
$ ./make
```

see [output](https://gist.github.com/abbood/2612edc8f0be3922f5c4e03301ad05c2)

the last part of `./make` gives me this

```
1 warning generated.
gcc -o catppt catppt.o pptparse.o charsets.o substmap.o fileutil.o confutil.o numutils.o ole.o  -lm
echo "#! /usr/bin/wish" >wordview
echo set charset_lib "\"/usr/local/share/catdoc\"">>wordview
cat wordview.tcl >>wordview
chmod 0755 wordview
touch build
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

then when i run `make install` i get this

```
make: `install' is up to date.
```

and obviously catdoc doesn't work:

```
$ which catdoc
>> nothing
```

## Question

How can I install this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use the built-in **textutil** to convert MS-Word documents to text:

```
textutil -stdout -cat txt SomeFile.doc
```

or

```
textutil -stdout -cat txt *.doc
```

Comment: good stuff! how can i do the same to a pdf file then? (awarded correct answer already, !featureCreep)

Comment: You can make a little script with **Automator** that extracts text from a PDF - I did it about 10 weeks ago then deleted it because I didn't think it'd be useful :-) This should get you started https://www.engadget.com/2013/02/11/mac-101-use-automater-to-extract-text-from-pdfs/

Comment: @abbood: for pdf you need `pdftotext` — on macos you can get it with `brew install poppler`

Answer (score 2):

## To build catdoc / catppt / xls2csv on Mac OS X (macos)

*tested with catdoc-0.95 on Mac OS X 10.9.5*

### Configuration

First, unless your documents are likely to be written in a Cyrillic language, start with:

*$* `./configure --with-input=cp1252 --with-output=mac-roman`

*(if you are more likely to encounter files from Windows)*

#### ... or ...

*$* `./configure --with-input=mac-roman --with-output=mac-roman`

*(if you are more likely to encounter files from MacOS)*

### Building

*$* `make all` (or just *$* `make`)

### Installation

```
make --directory=src install; make --directory=doc install; make --directory=charsets install
```

**This should compensate for the error you received, [abbood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/766570/abbood).** It appears the primary Makefile isn't running the install portion of the three subdirectories, for some reason. If a permissions error is reported, precede the above command with "`sudo`".

*I don't believe this should be necessary, but I'm not familiar enough with makefiles to provide a more proper (textbook) fix.*

---

One can, of course, get the same effect by:

```
$ cd src
$ make install
$ cd ../doc
$ make install
$ cd ../charsets
$ make install
$ cd ..
```

### Cleanup

To remove all files created by `make`, type:

- *$* `make clean`

To remove all files created by `make` as well as those created by `./configure`, type

- *$* `make distclean`

---