# Search a folder Directory for Text/Strings Located in Word.docx TABLES

Tags: python, ms-word

For my job, i am looking to be able to search lots of Word files for specific text. However this text is located in Word files (docx and doc) within any number of tables. I am trying to do a keyword search just to print the filename the text is located in. The following code below runs howeve it is finding no results. Please help.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob
import os
from os import listdir
from docx import Document
import re
import win32com.client as win32

Keyword = 'the'
#pattern = re.compile(Keyword)
documents = r'C:\Users\aac1928\Desktop\Test'

#Searches for Keywords in Converted Text Documents
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(documents, onerror=None):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith(".doc") or filename.endswith("docx"):
            file_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
            try:
                    with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
                        doc = Document(f)
                        for table in doc.tables:
                            for i, row in enumerate(table.rows):
                                if Keyword in Cell.text:
                                    print(filename)
                                    continue
            except Exception:
                pass
```

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `numpy` - kindly do not spam the tags (removed).

Comment: You really don't need to use python to go this, it is a regex search. There might be other easier alternatives, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11462184/search-ms-word-files-in-a-directory-for-specific-content-in-linux).

Comment: @KenDekalb thank you Ken! however at my current location at my job python is the easiest way for me to complete this lol

Answer (score 0):

I am relativity new to Python, However by adding to following code:

```
    except Exception:
        pass
        traceback.print_exc()
```

to your code I can see that Cell is not defined

If you change your loop to a while it will work e.g.

```
 for table in doc.tables:
                            for row in table.rows:
                                i = 0

                                while i < len(row.cells):
                                    if Keyword in row.cells[i].text:
                                        print(filename)
                                        continue
```

Hope it helps

**UPDATE :**

```
import numpy as np
import glob
import os
from os import listdir
from docx import Document
import re
import win32com.client as win32
import traceback

Keyword = 'the'
#pattern = re.compile(Keyword)
documents = r'C:\Users\aac1928\Desktop\Test'

#Searches for Keywords in Converted Text Documents
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(documents, onerror=None):
    print("Here 1")
    for filename in files:
        print(filename)
        if filename.endswith(".doc") or filename.endswith("docx"):
            file_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
            print(file_path)
            try:
                    with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
                        doc = Document(f)
                        for table in doc.tables:
                            for row in table.rows:
                                i = 0
                                while i < len(row.cells):
                                    if Keyword in row.cells[i].text:
                                        print(filename)
                                        continue
            except Exception:
                pass
                traceback.print_exc()
```

**UPDATE 2 :**

```
import numpy as np
import glob
import os
from os import listdir
from docx import Document
import re
import win32com.client as win32
import traceback

Keyword = 'the'
#pattern = re.compile(Keyword)
documents = r'C:\Users\aac1928\Desktop\Test'

documentsWithKeyword = []

#Searches for Keywords in Converted Text Documents
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(documents, onerror=None):
    print("Here 1")
    for filename in files:
        print(filename)
        if filename.endswith(".doc") or filename.endswith("docx"):
            file_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
            print(file_path)
            try:
                    with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
                        doc = Document(f)
                        for table in doc.tables:
                            for row in table.rows:
                                i = 0
                                while i < len(row.cells):
                                    if Keyword in row.cells[i].text:
                                        documentsWithKeyword.append(filename)
                                        continue
            except Exception:
                pass
                traceback.print_exc()

# remove duplicates
documentsWithKeyword = list(set(documentsWithKeyword))

documentsWithKeyword.sort()

#print documents that have the word
for docwithKeyword in documentsWithKeyword
    print(docwithKeyword)
```

Comment: thanks so much!! i used some of your code and modified it with what i came up with. Works perfectly! However, the continue statement is printing off multiple filenames for each instance it finds. I just want it to be if Keyword is found print(filename) then move on to the next file without iterating though the rest of the tables

Comment: Added a update, it will add each entry to a list and then remove the duplicate entries at the end and print each one, not the most efficent but should work!

Answer (score 0):

Performing your script in a try except "everything" is not a good idea when writing your code (not ever really). Also the manner in which you access the data does not seem to be correct, this should work though:

```
import numpy as np
import glob
import os
from os import listdir
from docx import Document
import re
import win32com.client as win32
import traceback

Keyword = 'the'
#pattern = re.compile(Keyword)
documents = r'C:\Users\aac1928\Desktop\Test'

def find_word():
    Keyword = 'the'
    #pattern = re.compile(Keyword)
    documents = r'/Users/marc/Documents'
    #Searches for Keywords in Converted Text Documents
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(documents):

        for filename in files:
            print filename
            if filename.endswith(".doc") or filename.endswith("docx"):
                file_path = os.path.join(root, filename)

                with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
                    doc = Document(f)
                    if search_doc(doc, Keyword):
                        print file_path


def search_doc(doc, Keyword):
    for table in doc.tables:
        for j, column in enumerate(table.columns):
            for i, row in enumerate(table.rows):
                if Keyword in table.cell(j, i).text:
                    return True
    return False
```

This also makes sure you stop looking for the keyword in the document if it is found and moves on to the next document instead of printing the filename several times if the keyword is found in several tables in the document.